# How to get handle on resize event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I need to know what handle is currently being dragged, east or west.

```
$("#mydiv").resizable({
    handles: 'e, w',
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        // to do: get active handle
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have, but didn't find, can you help?

Comment: @alex answered, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the event object:

```
var west = $(event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-resizable-w');
```

Comment: This does not work in Firefox 20, where event.srcElement is `undefined`. In Firefox 20 `e.originalEvent.target` does work, but not reliably (often returns the element below the draggable).

Comment: Use e.target instead of e.srcElement in Firefox

Answer (score 7):

with jquery has class it works too slowly, just use

```
if(ui.position.left != ui.originalPosition.left) //for west resize
```

then you can know east or west was resized

Answer (score 5):

```
$( '#mydiv' ).resizable({
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
        // this will return direction as "n", "e", "s", "se" etc.
        var $direction = $( this ).data( 'resizable' ).axis;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

it's easier than that, just get the target of the event (which is the DOM element that triggered the event)

```
$(event.target)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (Resizable start event)

```
if (e.toElement.className.indexOf("ui-resizable-w") >= 0) {
  console.log('west');
} else if (e.toElement.className.indexOf("ui-resizable-e") >= 0) {
  console.log('east');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in jQuery UI v1.11.4

```
$(event.target).data('uiResizable').axis
```